# How to configure plugin "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" in config.xml

Tags: phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
```

After I fetched the plugin **cordova-plugin-screen-orientation** with the line above I looked inside the config.xml and I couldn't find a similar line like below for the plugin.

```xml
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
```

I already tried

- guessing the plugin id/name (PhoneGap Build kept saying the plugin is unsupported):

```xml
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.screen-orientation" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" />
```

The last line is the plugin id/name from the plugins plugin.xml.

- to find the plugin id/name on the sites below:

  - [build.phonegap.com/plugins](http://build.phonegap.com/plugins)
  - [plugins.telerik.com/cordova](http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova?start=0&search=screen-orientation&collection=plugins_telerik_cordova)
  - [cordova.apache.org/plugins](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/)
- to get help by making an issue at [the repository of the plugin](https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation/) *(the issue has been deleted so I removed the link to the issue)*
- searching on stackoverflow and google with:

  - configure plugin phonegap
  - adding plugin to phonegap
- adding **src="npm"**:

```xml
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" src="npm" />`
```

Can someone tell me the plugin id/name or how to configure the plugin in the config.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is replacing `src="npm"` with `source="npm"`.

```xml
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" source="npm" version="1.4.0" />
```

Credits go to https://github.com/bau720123 for giving me the solution in the issue I created on GitHub. The issue is deleted so I can't post a link to it.

For more info on how to configure a plugin in the config.xml go here:
http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/plugins/