# Cordova screen lockOrientation is not a function

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm using cordova and I am trying to lock the screen orientation to landscape for Android. I'm using the plugin screen-orientation plugin:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation

I'm using it in my javascript code as:

```
screen.lockOrientation("landscape");
```

But I get the error that screen.lockOrientation is not a function. I console.log(screen) and I see that the method does exist. I also added the plugin into my config.xml as the same question was asked here:
[How to configure plugin "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" in config.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33563975/how-to-configure-plugin-cordova-plugin-screen-orientation-in-config-xml)

I'm still getting the error. Does anyone know how I can fix it?

Comment: if `screen` is not defined, then the plugin is not installed correctly. If building locally, remove/re-add it. If using a remote build service (e.g. Phonegap Build), ensure config.xml is configured correctly.

Comment: @DaveAlden I have tried re-adding it and my config file contains the plugin but I still get error.

Comment: any solution on this?

Comment: @BraianMellor no I haven't found a solution on this yet.

Comment: Can you add your index.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for ionic 1.X.

man after a long struggle I found it out myself, never said in any documentation. 
First I used ionic native as said here (take the part for v1 - angular1)
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/

then

Use injector '$cordovaScreenOrientation'. Will work only in device.

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope,$cordovaScreenOrientation) {
      $cordovaScreenOrientation.lockOrientation('landscape')
```

....

Answer (score 1):

As per the [npm documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation), you can use

`window.screen.orientation.lock('portrait');`